# VGA to HDMI Adapter unsupported signal, check device output

Tags: hdmi, vga, ubuntu-16.04, debian-jessie, dell-poweredge

It's been pretty tough trying to get the following setup to work:

```
1) Dell PowerEdge R710 (Video Card MGA G200eW WPCM450)
2) Sony Bravia 40" as Monitor
3) VGA to HDMI converter
3) Ubuntu Xenial Or Debian Jessie
```

Converter [link is here](http://www.microcenter.com/product/444605/vga_to_hdmi_with_audio_converter)

On Xenial or rather because upstream [version](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1316035/comments/7) of Xorg removed XAA, the `G200eW WPCM450` is not fully recognized.

I am using a 19" monitor for testing / OS installs and even on that the resolution is terrible.

There's a display for the TV but it's only shown as `Unknown Monitor` with a single resolution and it's not useful.

Debian Jessie on the other hand has a crisp clear picture on the 19" monitor and shows full resolution options.

However Jessie shows `unsupported signal, check device output` on the TV.

What am I missing here? How can I resolve this? I realize it's not practical to use a `PowerEdge` this way but I am too far down the rabbit hole to stop now!

Comment: I have a similar converter which uses Explore Micro chips, and it is not capable of any resolution conversion.  So you have to find a (VGA) resolution that the Dell/Matrox can output that is compatible with the Sony TV (which is likely to be only the standard video resolutions of 1080p, 1080i, 720p, 480p and 480i).  The Matrox appears to be incapable of generating any compatible resolution for the Sony TV.

Comment: @sawdust I tried that today several times using $ cvt 1920 1080 , then created the new mode and set the mode on the display with a refresh rate of 60 like so: xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1920x1080 -r 60

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck! Any other thoughts on this?

Comment: I cannot find any specs for the Matrox that indicate it's capable of the 1080p resolution that you're trying.  IMO you're wasting your time.